# Is car body same thing as frame (or chassis)

Tags: body, chassis

I am confused - [this](https://aluminium-guide.com/en/kuzov-audi-a2-alyuminievye-splavy-i-texnologii/) article says that car body weight only 153kg. For a car's frame that is very little (as far as I know). Or do they mean body as all the outside parts - bonnet, doors, etc. - not frame itself?

Can car's frame weight so little?

Comment: *For a car's frame that is very little (as far as I know).* They say it was 43% 'smaller' than for a steel body.

Answer (score 3):

Since the article in question was originally in Russian or some other Slavic language (based on the Cyrillic writing in the graphics), then translated into english, I think there may be a bit of translation loss, at least to me as an english speaker.

That said, it seems like they may be combining the two parts of body and frame into the 153kg. They are two separate groups of parts. They state in the article the entire car, dressed out (complete weight without passengers or cargo) is 825kg, which is ***very light*** for an automotive passenger car. This would include the engine, tires, wheels, interior, glass parts, suspension, etc. These "other parts" besides the body and frame could easily weigh in around the difference. So my bottom line here (and it is a guess) is that they are including both the frame and body parts into the 156kg amount they listed.

The whole point of the article was to tout Audi's use of lightweight alloys versus using steel and the ability to reach 2.99 liters per 100km fuel consumption (first "3 liter" vehicle).